# Assigning variables (foreach loop for parsing list)

Tags: c#

I am using `Concat` to join two lists into one:

```
var results = firstPart.Concat(secondPart);
```

Then I want to assign variable for each item in list as I am using them in methods. This is working but I think this is bad coding as it is assigning variables X amount of times (as much assigning as there are records in the list)?.

Here is current code:

```
            foreach (var item in results)
            {

                var NRO = item.NRO.TrimStart().TrimEnd();
                var NRO1 = item.NRO1.TrimStart().TrimEnd();
                var SNAME = item.SNAME.TrimStart().TrimEnd();
                var NAMEA = item.NAMEA.TrimStart().TrimEnd();
                var NAMEB = item.NAMEB.TrimStart().TrimEnd();
                var LY = item.LY.TrimStart().TrimEnd();

                Console.WriteLine(
                    NRO + " " + NRO1 + " " + SNAME + " " +
                    NAMEA + " " + NAMEB + " " + LY
                    );

                CreateCustomer(
                NRO, NRO1, SNAME, NAMEA, NAMEB, LY);

            }

    public static void CreateCustomer(string NRO, string NRO1, string SNAME,
        string NAMEA, string NAMEB, string LY)
```

Is there any better solution for this?

Comment: Unless you can show us the complete code I can't suggest anything better than what you have.

Comment: You should just use .Trim() is the equivalent of .TrimStart().TrimEnd() and if you trimmed the values in item when they're assigned then you could just use e.g. item.NRO directly without having to assign it to another variable first.

Comment: Unless there are millions of items in the list, it's unlikely to cause a problem. If you think doing so improves readability, keep it until a problem is evident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with what you have. The variables you create will be short-lived, so there's no memory waste. The JIT compiler would probably even inline them into the object constructor if you didn't have the `Console.WriteLine()` (but don't get rid of that just for that reason - the difference will be negligible).

Answer (score 2):

There is no harm, these variable will be destroyed once your for block is over. But few suggestion for improvement.

1. Use `.Trim()` instead of `.TrimStart().TrimEnd()`
2. If Possible move the implementation of `CreateCustomer()` inside your result item class - so you will have to use `item.CreateCustomer()` only
3. Its better to write placeholder `"{0}/{1}"` in Console.WriteLine() insteadof plus(+) concatenation

Happy Coding